Connection error from GCP Composer (Airflow) to GCP PubSub
I'm trying to subscribe to a GCP PubSub to get the messages from GCP Composer but got the following error:
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The conn_id `google_cloud_default` isn't defined

My DAG code is the following:
subscribe_pubsub_task = PubSubPullSensor(
  task_id="subscribe_pubsub",
  project_id=GCP_REPORTING_ID,
  subscription=PUBSUB_SUBSCRIPTION,
  ack_messages=True,
  deferrable=True,
)

I've reviewed the Airflow docs: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/pubsub/index.html
How to get connection id using GCP Service Account to authenticate?

Solved with custom Airflow connection for GCP.
The connection implementation looks like the following code:
PUBSUB_CONNECTION = 'gcp_pubsub_reporting'
PUBSUB_CLIENT = Connection(
  conn_id=PUBSUB_CONNECTION,
  conn_type='google_cloud_platform'
)
scopes = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
]
conn_extra = {
  "extra__google_cloud_platform__scope": ",".join(scopes),
  "extra__google_cloud_platform__project": GCP_REPORTING_ID,
  "extra__google_cloud_platform__keyfile_dict": json.loads(GCP_PUBSUB_CREDENTIALS),
}
conn_extra_json = json.dumps(conn_extra)
PUBSUB_CLIENT.set_extra(conn_extra_json)

if not (session.query(Connection).filter(Connection.conn_id == PUBSUB_CLIENT.conn_id).first()):
  session.add(PUBSUB_CLIENT)
  session.commit()
else:
  msg = f'Airflow connection with conn_id: {PUBSUB_CLIENT.conn_id} already exists'
  print(msg)

The task implementation looks like the following code:
subscribe_pubsub_task = PubSubPullSensor(
    task_id="subscribe_pubsub",
    project_id=GCP_REPORTING_ID,
    subscription=PUBSUB_SUBSCRIPTION,
    gcp_conn_id=PUBSUB_CONNECTION,
    ack_messages=True,
    deferrable=False,
    max_messages=1,
    mode='poke',
    poke_interval=20
)

